# PHP Cookie Not Saving

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I'm having this problem where the cookie not saving, and it has to do with the domain.

I am setting the domain like:

```
$cookie_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

And setting it like:

```
setcookie($name, $value, time() + $cookie_lifetime, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain, $cookie_secure, $cookie_httponly);
```

And it doesn't not work. But if I do:

```
setcookie($name, $value, time() + $cookie_lifetime, $cookie_path, '', $cookie_secure, $cookie_httponly);
```

Its fine. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

What is `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` value?

According to [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php): The domain that the cookie is available to. To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com (including example.com itself) then you'd set it to '.example.com'. Although some browsers will accept cookies without the initial ., » RFC 2109 requires it to be included. Setting the domain to 'www.example.com' or '.www.example.com' will make the cookie only available in the www subdomain.